# Optimizing join filters with Globally unique keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join

I have 2 tables, one **Base** table with a reference to another **Link** table.

All keys are unique across the database. Each table has a column `Market` to tell us which market each row of data belongs to. I'm only interested in data for a particular market (say X)

The question I have, is that if I am to join the 2 tables (I'm hoping to understand the cases of both an inner join and a left join (Base_Table LEFT JOIN Link_Table)) does having a Market filter of X on both tables help performance? Data-wise, all I need is to have a market filter on my base table to ensure I get data for Market X, But does having the filter on my link table affect performance in case of :

1. Inner join
2. Left join 
   Sample Queries :

/*INNER JOIN*/

```
SELECT --COLUMNS required--
FROM
<Base Table> bt
JOIN
<Link Table> lt
ON
bt.link_column - lt.ID
WHERE 
bt.Market = X
AND 
lt.Market = X
```

---

/*LEFT JOIN*/

```
SELECT --COLUMNS required>--
FROM
<Base Table> bt
LEFT JOIN
<Link Table> lt
ON
bt.link_column - lt.ID
AND lt.Market = X
WHERE 
bt.Market = X
```

Does the filter clause lt.Market = X affect performance at all?

Unfortunately, We do not have the permissions to view indexes on the tables.

EDIT :
I just checked with a colleague who has elevated permissions, the "tables" that I was taking about are actually views, and they do not seem to have any indexes defined on them. We have no access to the underlying tables. However I did manage to get the execution plans for 2 queries, as below. Hope they help.

The Base View is named "Order"
and the link view is named "call"
Order has call id and so refers to call. Both views have a column to indicate market

With the Market filter on both tables: 
[Filter on both tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f6Gb.png)

Market Filter on the base table :
[Filter on base table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCLoN.png)

Comment: What is a filter?  Post a sample queries.

Comment: @Frisbee - Added them to the question.

Comment: Why the minus in `bt.link_column - lt.ID`?

Comment: Without schema information this is impossible to answer. All possible 3 variants could be in any order regarding performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot view indexes then you probably cannot view the query plan.

It will depend.  If bt.link_column and lt.ID are both indexed then Market on both may actually slow it down.  You would have to see the query plan.

All else equal the optimizer will typically process the smaller table first so put Market on that table.

There is no guarantee that the Market will be the same in both tables.  Your data happens to be that way. Data repeating in multiple tables (or columns) is not 3NF. If an ID is associated with a single market then that relationship should be in a single table.

```
select * 
from <market Table> mt
join <Base Table> bt
  on bt.ID = mt.ID 
 and mt.Market = X 
JOIN <Link Table> lt
  ON bt.link_column = lt.ID
```

You can move mt.Market = X to the where

If you only have two tables then Base Table is Market Table and you can drop Market Table.  Market should only be in one table.